# Visual Studio 2019 SSRS Report Preview Not Working

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, sqlreportingservice

Anyone else having an issue when attempting to view a report with multiple dependent parameters?

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Create a report with two or more parameters that do not allow blank or null values where the available values are pulled from a dataset.
- At least one of the datasets used to populate a parameter is dependent on the selection of the previous parameter (SQL statement has WHERE value = @Parameter)
- Create a table to display the data on the report.
- Click on the Preview tab.
- Select the parameters.
- Click View Report.

The report does not display.

If the parameters are altered to use default values, previewing the report does work.

Visual Studio: 16.11.6
SQL Server Data Tools 16.0.6211.27130
SQL Server Reporting Services 15.0.19528.0

Comment: I'm using almost the exact same versions, by SSDT version is slightly older (16.0.62111.1170) but I have no issues. Have you tried deleting the `.rdl.data` file associated with the report from the project folder? This plus a reboot normally resolves any issues I have that have no obvious explanation.

Comment: I wish those actions would resolve it, but it doesn't. Happens in all of my projects, to old reports and new reports. Happens to other team members, too. Reboots and deleting the rdl.data file doesn't correct the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what could cause that. My versions for reference. `Visual Studio 2019 16.11.7` ; `SQL Server Data Tools 16.0.62111.11070` ; `SQL Server Reporting Services 15.0.19528.0`